# golang sort.Strings vs unix sort, how do I sort according to a given collation?

Tags: sorting, go, collation

I was puzzled for a while because the two methods of sorting behave differently, or at least in my environment. After a while, I realized it's because of different sorting rules.

A quick experiment illustrates my point:

```sh
$ foo() { echo "o'4" "o'neil" o-ciclo-music ó-do-forró  o-1 o-2 o-3 "o'" "o'1"  "o'2" aaa b bb; } 
$ foo | s2n | LC_ALL=C  sort  > /tmp/s.c
$ foo | s2n | LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" sort  > /tmp/s.u
$ paste /tmp/s.{c,u}  | awk '{ printf "%16s %s\n", $1 , $2 ; }'
             aaa aaa
               b b
              bb bb
              o' o'
             o'1 o'1
             o'2 o-1
             o'4 o'2
          o'neil o-2
             o-1 o-3
             o-2 o'4
             o-3 o-ciclo-music
   o-ciclo-music ó-do-forró
      ó-do-forró o'neil
```

The left column is sorted according to ascii-rules while the right column is sorted according to utf8 rules. The golang `sort.Strings()` behaves according to ascii rules. That function is based on the `<` and `=` operators and they in turn operates on integers. So the words are being sorted according to the ascii ordinal values of their letters.

It it possible to influence how sort.Strings() behaves based on some environment variable?  I have tried with the LC_ALL variables, but the 'a' < 'b' behavior in Golang is not influenced by that. This is probably for the better.

I am wondering which package provides a function with the same signature (and return type)
as strings.Compare(), but will heed some arbitrary collation rule-set (or at least unicode).

I want a function that indicates that o'neil should come *after* ó-do-forró.

```
       foobar.SetCollation(unicode)
       foobar.Compare(`o'neil`, `ó-do-forró`) -> 1
```

What package am I looking for?

Comment: [`golang.org/x/text/collate`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/collate)

Answer (score 0):

```
import  "golang.org/x/text/collate"

(...)

cull := collate.New(language.English,
    collate.IgnoreCase, collate.IgnoreDiacritics, collate.IgnoreWidth, 
    collate.Loose,
    collate.Force,
    collate.Numeric)
println(cull.CompareString( "o'neil", "ó-do-forró", )) // prints 1
println(cull.CompareString( "b", "a", )) // prints 1
```

Comment: It's interesting, that for me, `coll.SortStrings` never sorts "ó-do-forró" right before "o'neil" (which is always sorted last)—no matter which options (and variations of english language I select).

Comment: @kostix same here. Not sure what collation options would produces `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" sort` results

Comment: it's not supposed to order o'neil before ó-do-forró. the result 1 indicates that it should come _after_.